# Delete folder and its content with command in PHP?

Tags: php, command-line

I want to delete folder and its content for example I want to delete folder in `"c:\xampp\htdocs\project\public\var\cache\deleteMe"`.

right now I am doing this.

```
system("rd /s /q deleteMe")
```

but it is not working because it is catching the file from root directory of my project `"c:\xampp\htdocs\project\"` from here so if i put "deleteMe" folder in root like this "c:\xampp\htdocs\project\deleteMe" so the above command will work.. but i want to delete this directory
 `"c:\xampp\htdocs\project\public\var\cache\deleteMe"`.

So how can I reach there ?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Comment: You should always use the full path to whatever you're deleting, don't risk mistakes

Comment: at first i was using unlink() but it was giving me permission error i tried chmod() and give permission but still dont work. so then i have come to this solution.. but now both not working :(

Comment: i have also tried full path it is also not working.

Comment: What about `chown` ? I'm fairly certain it's still a permission error, full path is flawless

Comment: i am giving full path in function like this `system("rd /s /q c:\xampp\htdocs\project\public\var\cache\deleteMe")` this is what you are saying right?

Comment: Use `ls -la` and make sure owner and group are correct for `c:\xampp\htdocs\project\public\var` on the `cache` directory and contents